# group by same key UUID across different event and subtract timestamp

Tags: math, facet, newrelic, nrql

I have two or more event with same Id like a session but with different attribute values I should query the all event grouped by id and calc the difference between two time stamps.

example of events

event one:

{
type: 'start',
Id: 1
...
}

event two:

{
type: 'end',
Id: 1
...
}

Pseudo query:

select (end.timrstamp-start.timestamp)/1000
group by Id

Answer (score 0):

I think the one possible solutions is

```
SELECT average(duration) FROM (
SELECT (
  (filter(latest(timestamp), where transitionName = 'STARTED') - 
  filter(latest(timestamp), where transitionName = 'CREATED'))
) AS 'duration'
FROM table 
FACET id AS uniqueId
SINCE last hour
```